# Prototype/jQuery conflict on getElementsByClassName in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, prototypejs

I've got jQuery 1.10 on a Magento 1.7.0.2 install, **in IE8 and below** I'm getting the following error:

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'getElementsByClassName' 
jquery.js, line 5109 character 13
```

This line is in bold below:

```
        if ( match && (context.nodeType === 1 || context.nodeType === 9) ) {
          // Speed-up: Sizzle("TAG")
          if ( match[1] ) {
            return makeArray( context.getElementsByTagName( query ), extra );

          // Speed-up: Sizzle(".CLASS")
          } else if ( match[2] && Expr.find.CLASS && context.getElementsByClassName ) {
            return makeArray( context.getElementsByClassName( match[2] ), extra );
          }
        }
```

I believe this is down to Prototype 1.7 causing a conflict with `getElementsByClassName`, is there a fix for this?

Comment: It's not supported in IE8, try `document.querySelectorAll('.' + match[2])`

Answer (score 0):

The function isn't supported in IE 8 or below:

http://caniuse.com/#search=getElementsByClassName